# QML: animation only when mouse enters image

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to make an animation when mouse comes over the image, but NOT when mouse leaves the image.

```
Item{
width: 800
height:800
Rectangle{
    id: blueRec
    width: 100; height: 100; color: "blue"
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            im1.visible = true
            im1.source = "1.png"
        }
    }
}
Image {
    id: im1
    scale: im1MouseArea.containsMouse ? 0.8 : 1.0
    Behavior on scale {
        NumberAnimation{
            id: anim
            from: 0.95
            to: 1
            duration: 400
            easing.type: Easing.OutBounce
        }
    }
    MouseArea{
        id: im1MouseArea
        hoverEnabled: true
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

}

The code above makes also animation, when mouse is leaving image.

Can someone help?

Comment: Could you clarify the behavior you're trying to achieve?  It's a little confusing because you're setting the scale to either 0.8 or 1.0, but then you're overriding those values in the NumberAnimation.

Comment: I want to make some bounce animation of the image when mouse goes over the image. This code is doing that, but I don't want that bounce animation, when mouse goes away of image area. And without line  scale: im1MouseArea.containsMouse ? 0.8 : 1.0 there will be no animation. No matter what numbers are there. I can use also  scale: im1MouseArea.containsMouse ? 1.0 : 1.0. Result is the same. It's strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the scale and then triggering an animation that alters the scale seems like an odd approach.  If I were you, I'd break this out into states and set the animation to trigger on the appropriate transition.

Here's an example of how this could be done:

```
Image {
    id: im1

    states: [ "mouseIn", "mouseOut" ]
    state: "mouseOut"

    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: "*"
            to: "mouseIn"
            NumberAnimation {
                target: im1
                properties: "scale"
                from: 0.95
                to: 1
                duration: 400
                easing.type: Easing.OutBounce
            }
        }
    ]

    MouseArea{
        id: im1MouseArea
        hoverEnabled: true
        anchors.fill: parent

        onContainsMouseChanged: {
            im1.state = containsMouse ? "mouseIn" : "mouseOut"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I cannot upvote because of low reputation, but when I reach that, I will do it.